# Where to ask questions about the "Wesnoth markup language"?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I have a question regarding the [Wesnoth markup language](http://wiki.wesnoth.org/ReferenceWML). But I am not sure where to ask:

- Gaming SE
- Gamedev SE

Where should I ask my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would appear to best fit on GameDev. It seems to be more about video game development than the game itself.